# Does the generalized Schoenflies theorem generalize the Schoenflies theorem?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

The object of study are topological embeddings $h\colon S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^n$, $n\ge2$. We have the

**Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem:** If $h\colon S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^n$ is an embedding, then $S^n-h(S^{n-1})$ has exactly two (path-)components. The components are both acyclic and have topological boundary $h(S^{n-1})$.

This theorem is easily accessible using algebraic topology. In case $h$ is the standard equatorial embedding, the closure of each component of $S^n-h(S^{n-1})$ is a disk. It is known that this is not the case in general (the Alexander horned sphere is the historical counterexample). The question of how pathologies can be avoided is answered by the

**Generalized Schoenflies theorem:** If $h\colon S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^n$ is an embedding and $A$ is the closure of a component of $S^n-h(S^{n-1})$, TFAE:

1. The embedding $h$ extends to an embedding $\tilde{h}\colon S^{n-1}\times[0,1]\rightarrow A$.
2. $A$ is a topological manifold with boundary.
3. $A\cong D^n$.

The implication 3.=>2. is trivial, the implication 2.=>1. a consequence of the existence of collar neighborhoods and 1.=>3. is the heart of the theorem. There also is the classical

**Schoenflies theorem:** If $h\colon S^1\rightarrow S^2$ is an embedding and $A$ is the closure of a component of $S^2-h(S^1)$, then $A\cong D^2$.

A popular alternative is the (I'm not entirely confident that I'm getting the naming conventions right here)

**Jordan-Schoenflies theorem:** If $h\colon S^1\rightarrow S^2$ is an embedding, there is a homeomorphism $H\colon S^2\rightarrow S^2$ extending $h$.

It is not hard to see that the last two theorems are equivalent. These are also often phrased in terms of embeddings $S^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ rather than $S^1\rightarrow S^2$, but translating between the corresponding versions is easy. My question is: Do these classical theorems, as the name suggests, actually follow from the generalized Schoenflies theorem? That is, is there an easy argument that every embedding $S^1\rightarrow S^2$ is automatically (bi-)collared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's nothing easier than just going through the proof of the original Schönflies Theorem.

I don't think there's any confusion here, everything is out in the open. The naive "generalization" of the Schönflies Theorem is false in higher dimensions. The weaker "generalization" - i.e. the one where the bicollared condition is incorporated as a hypothesis - is true. The "generalization" terminology is useful here but it should not be over-interpreted.

Comment: That is a shame. But thanks.

Comment: Well but that's the reality. I actually think that the proof of the original Schönflies Theorem is more difficult than the Brown-Mazur proof of the generalized one; the latter has a certain slickness to it; the former is all nuts and bolts.